# How to convert large iMovie-imported videos preservig aspect ratio?

Tags: conversion, imovie

I have a camcorder that does 1024x576 videos imported from a camera on a MacBook, using iMovie. But, those videos are H.264 encoded (I think), and that's not convenient for sharing where most of my viewers use Windows.

I tried to convert it of course, but every program (even Mac OS) *think* my video is 720x576-encoded, so when I convert them the aspect ratio is not conserved.

[image]

As you can see on this screenshot, took from QuickTime info, the "normal size" of that video is "1024x576". But all other programs, including Mac OS, only *see* the 720x576 (in the Format line here).

Mac OS :

[image]

Any Video Converter Ultimate :

[image]

SkySoft iMedia Converter :

[image]

I get stuck.

Do you know a way to convert large-width iMove imported videos to other formats preserving aspect-ratio ?

Comment: What about using compressor?

Comment: There is no trial, I don't want to risk 50 boxes... But thank you anyway

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an issue with non-square pixels? Any player worth using will probably deal with it properly. Why are you re-encoding in the first place? Because the files are too big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent my eveening but finally found a working software. That's not a freeware :( 69 boxes, but it works so I'll buy it. This is [Wondershare Video Converter Ultimate](http://www.wondershare.net/active/video-converter-ultimate-mac.html).

[image]

Don't hesitate to edit this answer if you feel that my answer is too spammy.

Happy converting

Comment: Wow, $1721.55? You didn't give much time for any free suggestions.

Comment: $1721.55? hell, no, $69

Comment: Duh. I assumed you purchased licenses for 69 computers.